# Permission denied mounting an existing volume (without sudo)

Tags: docker, docker-volume

Following setup:

I am a `username` on a machine. I am in the `docker` group such that I can run docker, which is installed on that machine.

I'm desperately trying to run [`jupyter/datascience-notebook`](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/datascience-notebook) on this machine but the problem is I cannot safe files there because the user does not seem to have access rights to the mounted directory.

It is supposed to work like this:

```sh
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 -v ~/workspaces:/home/jovyan/work/ -e NB_UID=$(id -u) -e NB_GID=$(id -g) -e GRANT_SUDO=yes jupyter/datascience-notebook
```

but it does not because I do not have `sudo` rights.

```sh
$ docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 -v ~/workspaces:/home/jovyan/work/ -e NB_UID=$(id -u) -e NB_GID=$(id -g) -e GRANT_SUDO=yes jupyter/datascience-notebook
Container must be run as root to set $NB_UID
Container must be run as root to set $NB_GID
Container must be run as root to grant sudo permissions
```

I was planning to play around with a `Dockerfile` so I started to write this:

```sh
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook

# Use user root
USER root

RUN ls -la ~/
RUN chown -R jovyan:users ~/.local         
RUN chmod -R 1777 ~/.local
RUN ls -la ~/
```

And here is the reason why: This little helper script below is supposed to create the image `test-image` and run it afterwards.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess
from notebook.auth import passwd

cmd = 'docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 ' \
    '-v ~/workspaces:/home/jovyan/work ' \
    '-v ~/datasets:/home/jovyan/data ' \
    '-e NB_UID=$(id -u) -e NB_GID=$(id -g) -e GRANT_SUDO=yes ' \
    'test-image start.sh jupyter lab ' \
    '--NotebookApp.token=\'\' '

print('Running {}'.format(cmd))


subprocess.call('docker build --rm -t test-image .', shell=True)
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

For reasons I **do not understand** I get the following output:

```
...
Step 14/16 : RUN ls -la ~/
 ---> Running in ef30926edc1a
total 44
drwsrwsr-x 12 jovyan users 4096 Feb 22 12:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root   root  4096 Feb 22 12:59 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 jovyan users  220 Aug 31  2015 .bash_logout
-rw-rw-r--  1 jovyan users 3771 Aug 31  2015 .bashrc
drwsrwsr-x  3 jovyan users 4096 Feb 20 11:41 .cache
drwsrwsr-x  3 jovyan users 4096 Feb 20 09:29 .conda
drwsrwsr-x  3 jovyan users 4096 Feb 20 11:41 .config
drwxrwsrwt 11 jovyan users 4096 Feb 22 12:59 .local
-rw-rw-r--  1 jovyan users  655 May 16  2017 .profile
drwsrwsr-x  2 jovyan users 4096 Feb 20 09:28 work
drwsrwsr-x  3 jovyan users 4096 Feb 20 09:38 .yarn
 ---> 2de66bf593f3
Removing intermediate container ef30926edc1a
Step 15/16 : RUN ls -la ~/.local/share
...
Set username to: jovyan
usermod: no changes
Set jovyan UID to: 1006
Set jovyan GID to: 1006
Granting jovyan sudo access and appending /opt/conda/bin to sudo PATH
Executing the command: jupyter lab --NotebookApp.token=
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 528, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'runtime_dir'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/bin/jupyter-lab", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(jupyterlab.labapp.main())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1366, in initialize
    self.init_configurables()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1100, in init_configurables
    connection_dir=self.runtime_dir,
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 535, in get
    value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 99, in _runtime_dir_default
    ensure_dir_exists(rd, mode=0o700)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/utils/__init__.py", line 13, in ensure_dir_exists
    os.makedirs(path, mode=mode)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/jovyan/.local/share'
```

So what happens there is that I am `chmod -R 1777 ~/.local` because I thought this might help me with the `Permission denied` error that you'd see at the end of this output.

I do not understand why this is not working. All I want to do is mount an existing directory into my docker container and be able to write files there.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while running a Docker container with --user although the Dockerimage for the respective container had no

```
USER mynamehere
```

in it. The line USER root is not such a good idea, you need to use another username if you want a dedicated user (doesn't matter which as long as its not root). This user can be mapped to fit your local uid/gui by adding

```
--user $(id -u):$(id -g)
```

to your docker run command-line.
After that, new files created in attached volumes should be created with the host user's name.

Note: I suggest to give the user mynamehere sudo rights in the Dockerfile by adding this right before the USER mynamehere line:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install sudo && \
    adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" udocker && \
    adduser udocker sudo && echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
```